# avoiding tags on tinyxml

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I'm using tinyXML to parse my XML documents, but I'm having a problem since I'm not a expert on it.

Considering this XML structure:

```
    <element>
      <element1>
        text1
        <element2>...</element2>
        text4
      </element1>
      <element3>
        text2
        <element4>...</element4>
        text3
      </element3>
    </element>
```

I know that on `element1` there´s text and a lot of elements (I don't know how many). How can I get all the text on `element1`, ignoring the elements in between?

I tried reaching the element I want and use `getText()`, but it only gets text until the next element (`element2` in this case), losing the rest of the text.

So, here is the first solution i tried:

```
void iterate(TiXmlNode* body) {

TiXmlNode* child;

for (child = body->FirstChild(); child; child = child->NextSibling())
{       
    if (child->Type() == TiXmlNode::TINYXML_TEXT)
        cout << child->Value() << endl;
    if (child->FirstChild())iterate(child->FirstChild());

    }
    return;
}
```

This function is supose to iterate to all the children of the main node and the grandchildren of the main node(if there are any)

It kinda works, but not 100%. Now it only outputs `text1` and then it jumps to `text2` it doesnt show `text3`or`text4`also not text between tags `element2` and `element4`(if there would be any)

---

Edited. It´s 100% functionall now.

Comment: OP, we need to see your attempts at solving this, Please provide an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The file you're trying to parse is not a valid XML, so don't expect it to work properly. You might want to use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: It is a valid XML, what i put is just a piece of the document. It´s too big to put it here.